# Creating report values that are stored in a meta table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id =422
```

My results look something like:

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key         | meta_value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4989    | 422     | _shipping_company| TEST
4970    | 422     | _shipping_lname  | Doe
4971    | 422     | _shipping_fname  | John
4972    | 422     | _billing_fname   | jdoe@gmail.com
```

What is the most efficient way to output these values to look something like:

```
order_id | shipping_company | Lname         | fname        | email
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
422      | TEST             | Doe           | John         | jdoe@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `PIVOT` for that but in MySQL you can use `GROUP BY` and `CASE` to flatten EAV like:

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71b9f/1/0)**

```
SELECT 
   post_id AS order_id,
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_shipping_company' THEN meta_value END ) AS shipping_company,
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_shipping_lname' THEN meta_value END ) AS Lname,
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_shipping_fname' THEN meta_value END ) AS fname,
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_billing_fname' THEN meta_value END ) AS email
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id =422 
GROUP BY post_id;
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
SELECT 
   post_id AS order_id,
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_shipping_company' THEN meta_value END ) AS shipping_company,
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_shipping_lname' THEN meta_value END ) AS Lname,
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_shipping_fname' THEN meta_value END ) AS fname,
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_billing_fname' THEN meta_value END ) AS email
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id =422 
GROUP BY post_id
) AS t
WHERE t.email IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for going into detail on your comment, however, if I remove the `post_id = 422`, my results include all `post_id` in the database with all NULL values. Is there a way to check against a field that will always be populated, like email?

Comment: @etm124 Sorry I don't understand you, please modify my fiddle and share link, I will check it

Comment: Sorry @lad2025 but fiddle keeps erroring out for me. Here is a screenshot when I run the query and remove the `where` clause. As you can see, I am returning all `order_id` with no meta data. I'd like to only include rows that have `email`. http://i.imgur.com/w1M3NuO.png

Comment: @etm124 add `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta AS w WHERE w.post_id = post_id AND meta_key = '_billing_fname')`

Comment: @etm124 See my updated answer, better to wrap it to subquery and check for NULL

Answer (score 0):

Here ist my answer

```
SELECT 
 post_id aorder_id  , GROUP_CONCAT( IF(meta_key ='_shipping_company', meta_value, NULL)) company
  , GROUP_CONCAT( IF(meta_key ='_shipping_lname', meta_value, NULL)) Lname
  , GROUP_CONCAT( IF(meta_key ='_shipping_fname', meta_value, NULL)) Fname
  , GROUP_CONCAT( IF(meta_key ='_billing_fname', meta_value, NULL)) email
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id = 422
GROUP BY post_id;
```

or delete the where for all row or use WHERE post_id in (422,423)